# R programming - dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

For a financial model to be coded using the `dplyr` package in R, I need to refer to `lag`ged and `lead` values of variables but I cannot seem to get the code for the `lag` function working as documented.

```
> library(dplyr)
> x <- seq(100,500,100)
> x
[1] 100 200 300 400 500
> lead(x,1)
[1] 200 300 400 500  NA
> lag(x,1)
Error in lag(x, 1) : unused argument (1)
>
```

I was expecting `lag(x,1)` to result in: `NA 100 200 300 400`.
Any advice?Thanks.

Comment: It gives me the expected result with `lag`.  Which version of `dplyr` you are using?  Can you try `dplyr::lag(x, 1)`

Comment: Works fine for me. Try it as `dplyr::lag(x, 1)`; the function masks `stats::lag`, so your namespaces might be getting confused. Reloading `dplyr` will also usually take care of it, but it's something to be aware of regardless—thus the warning when you load `dplyr`.

Answer (score -1):

`lag` is a bit of a strange function with R. It only works as expected with time-series objects. For instance:

```
cbind(x = ts(1:10), y = lag(1:10, -1))
```

gives you:

```
    x  y
    1 NA
    2  1
    3  2
    4  3
    5  4
    6  5
    7  6
    8  7
    9  8
    10  9
    NA 10
```

If you want a quick and dirty function to do what you want I'd use this:

```
lag_n <- function(x, n) {c(rep(NA, n), x)[1:length(x)])}
```

In your case it gives:

```
lag_n(seq(100,500,100),1)
[1]  NA 100 200 300 400
```

Edit: Whoops. This is talking about `stats::lag`. I get the expected result with `dplyr::lag`. Though I will leave this here for the future.